# Im getting a Index Error, when i tried to make a dummy console game with basic oop

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, random

Now i will give you more details, the game has max 10 min 6 players,they should randomly choose another player and attack them. So here in for loop i am tring to randomly choose who is gonna atack and who is going to get hurt, but it gives error

```
import random

class Fighter:
    def __init__(self, name, health, power, stamina):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.power = power
        self.stamina = stamina
        self.fighter_stats = [self.name, self.health, self.power, self.stamina]

    @classmethod
    def Get_Hurt(cls):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def Attack(cls):
        pass

fighters_list = []
atackers_list = []
dummy_value = 0
fighter_num = random.randint(6, 10)
atackers_num = random.randint(1, 6)

for i in range(1, fighter_num + 1):
    fighter_health = random.randint(55, 100)
    fighter_power = random.randint(20, 35)
    fighter_stamina = random.randint(3, 7)
    fighter = Fighter(f"fighter{i}", fighter_health, fighter_power, fighter_stamina)
    fighters_list.append(fighter.name)
    dummy_value += 1
    while True:    #this while loop is for making sure if the for loop is in its last loop  
        if dummy_value != fighter_num + 1:
            dummy_value += 1
            continue
        else:
            for i in range(atackers_num):
                rand_attacker = random.choice(fighters_list)
                atackers_list.append(rand_attacker)
                fighters_list.remove(rand_attacker)
            break

print(fighters_list)
print(atackers_list)
```

And that is the console output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\azaz9\PycharmProjects\oyrenme\yoxlama.py", line 38, in <module>
    rand_attacker = random.choice(fighters_list)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\random.py", line 378, in choice
    return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You don't need the while loop, just increase the dummy_value, then do the for loop

Comment: You put ONE thing in `fighters_list`, then pick it (with `choice`), then remove it from the list (so the list is empty), then you try to pick again : that fails

Comment: BUT you have a strange version of python, in my python there is a verification that what you passe to "choice" isn't empty

Comment: I thing the while loop should be AFTER the first for loop that initlalize the things, not into it

Comment: thank you very much i understood the problem

Comment: Also be careful with naming both loop variables `i`, when they are nested! (rows 25, 37)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- your `while` loop is useless, that is just the following code

  ```
  dummy_value = fighter_num + 1

  for i in range(atackers_num):
      rand_attacker = random.choice(fighters_list)
      atackers_list.append(rand_attacker)
      fighters_list.remove(rand_attacker)
  ```
- the first for loop initializes the stuffs, the "while" loop (or just the main code) should be outside/after it

Resulting in

```
for i in range(1, fighter_num + 1):
    fighter_health = random.randint(55, 100)
    fighter_power = random.randint(20, 35)
    fighter_stamina = random.randint(3, 7)
    fighter = Fighter(f"fighter{i}", fighter_health, fighter_power, fighter_stamina)
    fighters_list.append(fighter.name)
    dummy_value += 1

dummy_value = fighter_num + 1

for i in range(atackers_num):
    rand_attacker = random.choice(fighters_list)
    atackers_list.append(rand_attacker)
    fighters_list.remove(rand_attacker)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending only one fither, and then trying to get the attackers.
In this way after the first iteration the list is empty and the subsequent call to .choice() fails.

You should append all the fighters, than choose the attackers:

```
fighters_list = []
atackers_list = []
dummy_value = 0
fighter_num = random.randint(6, 10)
atackers_num = random.randint(1, 6)

for i in range(1, fighter_num + 1):
    fighter_health = random.randint(55, 100)
    fighter_power = random.randint(20, 35)
    fighter_stamina = random.randint(3, 7)
    fighter = Fighter(f"fighter{i}", fighter_health, fighter_power, fighter_stamina)
    fighters_list.append(fighter.name)
    dummy_value += 1
while True:    #this while loop is for making sure if the for loop is in its last loop  
    if dummy_value != fighter_num + 1:
        dummy_value += 1
        continue
    else:
        for i in range(atackers_num):
            print(len(fighters_list))
            rand_attacker = random.choice(fighters_list)
            atackers_list.append(rand_attacker)
            fighters_list.remove(rand_attacker)
        break

print(fighters_list)
print(atackers_list)
```

Comment: Sorry the both answers are coreect, but i cant mar them both as correct and because of my rating i cant rate you as a thank.